# Getting error while defining AIF channels

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I am using client instance of dynamics Ax 2009.

While defining channels for AIF I encountered a error and the error message is given below.

"Path %1 does not have file write permissions".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a breakpoint on of the `info.add` method. Then work backwards.